# Why NVCC is unable to match function definition to an existing declaration?

Tags: cuda

I have this files that produce the following error when compiling with nvcc

```
error C2244: 'TemplateClass<N>::print': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration 
note: see declaration of 'TemplateClass<N>::print' 
note: definition note: 'void TemplateClass<N>::print(const std::string [])' 
note: existing declarations note: 'void TemplateClass<N>::print(const std::string [N])'
```

**Template.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned int N>
class TemplateClass
{
private:
    std::string name;

public:
    TemplateClass();
    TemplateClass(const std::string& name);
    void print(const std::string familyName[N]);
};

#include "template.inl"
```

**Template.inl**

```
template <unsigned int N>
TemplateClass<N>::TemplateClass()
{
    name = "Unknown";
}

template <unsigned int N>
TemplateClass<N>::TemplateClass(const std::string& name)
{
    this->name = name;
}

template <unsigned int N>
void TemplateClass<N>::print(const std::string familyName[N])
{
    std::cout << "My name is " << name << " ";
    for (auto i = 0; i < N; i++)
        std::cout << familyName[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

**consume_template.cu**

```
#include "template.h"

void consume_template_gpu()
{
    TemplateClass<3> obj("aname");
    std::string namesf[3];
    namesf[0] = "un";
    namesf[1] = "deux";
    namesf[2] = "trois";
    obj.print(namesf);
}
```

I am using VS2017 15.4.5, later versions failed to create the project with CMake.

The project was created with CMake like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(template_inl_file LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

set (lib_files template.h consume_template.cu)
add_library(template_inl_file_lib ${lib_files})
```

Comment: You are missing the file `consume_template.cpp`.

Comment: it does not matter for the problem, it happens when including the `template.h` in the .cu file. Let me edit my post to avoid confusion.

Comment: It compiles with `nvcc` and `gcc`. In my case `gcc` complained about the `auto` in the `for` loop from `template.inl`, but changing that to `int` was all I had to do to compile your file.

Comment: Maybe is a problem of VS?

Comment: It only happens when I do `#include <template.h>` in the `cu` file. If I do the include in the `cpp` file it works perfectly fine.

Comment: On CUDA 9.1 on linux it works for me in a `cu` file.  Not enough info here to determine where the issue is, and I'm not going to hack my way thru CMake to see if there is an error there.  If you're not using CUDA 9.1 you might want to try that.  Or feel free to file a bug at developer.nvidia.com

Comment: @RobertCrovella yes, I'm using CUDA 9.1 with all of 3 patches they've released. What more info can I provide? It is weird that it works when there is no nvcc involved in the process but fails when it is. I'll file a bug.

Comment: The most obvious point is that the error isn't being emitted by nvcc, it is being emitted by [VS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf190ysd.aspx). So at best what is happening is that nvcc is producing code that VS can't compile. That should be easy to check

Comment: @talonmies could you give me some pointers on how to do that?

Comment: The --keep option will save the intermediate code in the build and the --verbose option will emit commands and output of all the intermediate steps in the compilation trajectory. Remember nvcc isn't a compiler and every step of compilation is done by other tools (and all of this is documented in the nvcc manual)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that the array is decaying into a pointer and the size of the array is lost during compilation. So this

```
template <unsigned int N>
void TemplateClass<N>::print(const std::string familyName[N]);
```

will be actually turned into this

```
template <unsigned int N>
void TemplateClass<N>::print(const std::string* familyName);
```

as we can see there is no way for the compiler to know that it has to generate different functions depending on the size of the array (i.e. the template parameter N).

To solve this we can use an old trick to avoid array decay like this

```
template <unsigned int N>
void TemplateClass<N>::print(const std::string (&familyName)[N]);
```

Now the size N is present through the compilation and the compiler knows there are different functions to be generated. I guess, as pointed out in the comments of the question that NVCC produces code that VS does not produce by itself and then it does not know how to handle it.

More info on the topic on the following links

http://pointer-overloading.blogspot.ch/2013/09/c-template-argument-deduction-to-deduce.html

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction

https://theotherbranch.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/template-parameter-deduction-from-array-dimensions/

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity , try using std::string namesf = {"un","deux","trois"}; It seems like a compiler issue. Trying different formats might help compiler to understand better. Otherwise code seems to be ok.
Maybe you're missing some linkage with CMake. Also try compiling straight from VS2017 without using CMake by creating a CUDA project.